# does jhipster intend to integrate flutter like angular / react / vue in the future?

Tags: flutter, jhipster

Flutter is a great framework for mobile app development.
And now, one can develop web with flutter, and it also has its own advantages over react native.
So will jhipster integrate flutter in the future?

Answer (score 0):

There are several articles and a JHipster module: https://github.com/merlinofcha0s/generator-jhipster-flutter.

As this module has currently only 37 stars on github, I doubt the dev team would want to integrate it into the core generator.

The fact that Flutter uses Dart would also require much effort from JHipster dev team.

That's only my opinion of course and things could evolve.